# createDrawerNavigator - inconsistent close behavior?

Tags: react-native

I've implemented react-navigation-drawer and I'm seeing some weird and inconsistent behavior.  Particularly when I click on the screen outside of the drawer:

1. Sometimes the drawer retracts smoothly as expected on the first outside click
2. Sometimes it takes 2-3 clicks outside of the drawer for the drawer to retract
3. Sometimes it takes 20+ clicks outside of the drawer for the drawer to retract
4. Sometimes the drawer doesn't retract, even after 50 clicks on the outside
5. Even when scenario #3 above occurs, the next time I open the drawer and then click on the outside, it often works perfectly on the first attempt

And sometimes the open/close test works perfectly as expected 20 times in a row.

Is this a known quirk with react-navigation-drawer in development mode?  Or does this seem like an issue that could impact the app in production?

Comment: Do you do many things when you see SideBar?

Comment: All I do is click on the outside to attempt to close it

Comment: Then check out the features that you perform when you touch an empty area.

Comment: I haven't written any code to handle when an empty area is touched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to handle outside click.
this often happens during development stage(assuming you are using android).
try closing js debugging that will be enough.
and if it'still continues then
try release variant and you'll notice the difference in performance. 
lot of other stuff goes on during development
and try to spot any possible memory leak in your code if problem continues